# How does Google+ auto-backup my photos on iOS in the background?

Tags: ios, google-plus, background-process

How is the Google+ app's photo auto-backup feature implemented given iOS 6.x constraints? It seems to able to upload my Camera Roll photos even when I'm no longer running the Google+ app.

The [iOS developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)
say, for short processes, "You need to perform a single finite-length task" and, for long-running processes, photo upload doesn't seem to be one of the [approved uses](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24).

Answer (score 4):

From what I've observer, G+ app is using significant location change api to wake up app & update photo stream. See [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) for technical info how to use this feature.

Comment: This seems like a serious abuse of the location API.